# How to check ownership of inner classes in Java

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I have the following structure:

```
public class Outer {
    public /*non-static*/ final class Inner {
        // to prevent instantiating other than in method `create`
        private Inner(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
        /* ... */
    }

    Inner create(/* ... */) {
        return new Inner(/* ... */);
    }

    void operateOn(Inner inner) {
        // TODO check if inner for this Outer instance
    }
}
```

and usage like this:

```
Outer manager = new Outer();
Inner state = manager.create(/* ... */);
```

and somewhere else

```
manager.operateOn(state);
```

*I want to create a fool-proof utility class, meaning `Outer.operateOn` would only accept `Inner` instances owned by itself*

I know that all non-static inner classes have a reference to (all) outer classes via `Outer.this` inside their class body.

I'm wondering if there's a better method for checking this than adding any method to `Inner` like `isOwnedBy(Outer outer) { return outer == Outer.this; }` or `getOwner() { return Outer.this }`.

Comment: Maybe a `void create(...) { this.inner = new Inner(); }` and `void operateOn() { this.inner.doSomething(); }`?

Comment: "meaning Outer.operateOn would only accept Inner instances owned by itself" How would any other Inner type be passed?

Comment: @assylias you can create multiple instances with create, it's not a 1:1 relation

Comment: @JamesB I want to prevent this: `Outer manager2 = new Outer(); Inner state2 = manager2.create(...); manager.operateOn(state2);` the accepted answer does exactly that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to create a fool-proof ....

that is always harder than you think.

> manager.operateOn(state);

If you know it has to the manager associated with the state, I wouldn't provide the manager.

Try instead

```
state.operate();
```

The `state` knows which `manager` it should be using. This way there is no way to specify an incorrect manager because you can't change the manager.

Comment: Hmm, I'm gonna accept this, however I may have made a mistake translating my current design into a SO question. I may post another one similar to this one.

Comment: @Keerthivasan +1 Thank you, I will take that as a general statement ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Peter said

```
class Inner{
     private Inner(Outer manager){
        this.manager = manager;
     }

     public void operate(){
          manager.operate(this);
     }

}
```

and `operate` method in manager should be private.

Comment: The whole point is that I have an inner class and the manager reference is automatically generated by the compiler.
The `operate` suggested by Peter would look like `Outer.this.operate(this)` in case of my code. Note: the `Outer.this.` is optional, compiler would resolve the right `operate` method based on the arguments and context.

Comment: The Outer would need to have a different name otherwise `operate(this);` would fail to compile.